# Converted training script from torch to lightning, but model is not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-lightning

I converted a working pytorch training script to pytorch lightning in order to utilize multiple GPUs in training. The training on GPUs itself is working fine and I was able to get the speed boost, but after training, the model isn't learning anything and is predicting (binary) everything around 0.5. The original pytorch script works when trained on a single GPU, so it's something during this conversion that probably went wrong.

The basic setup is:

- I use a pretrained transformer, and freeze the encoder parameters,
- I connect encoder output to a multi-class classifier head and a binary classifier head,
- I'm only focusing on the binary classifier, the multi-class head is just for the model to learn a bit more.

What I have tried:

- disable auto optimization and implement pytorch optimization (zero_grad, backward, step) within `training_step`.
- increase/decrease batch size
- increase learning_rate
- try training only on 1 GPU with this same script
- try 2-3 GPUs

None of them seems to be working for me and when I check the parameter values in the saved checkpoint, it looks like it's just after initialization.

Did I miss anything very important here? I only froze the transformer weights, but not the linear classifiers.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration

class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, model_name, tokenizer, num_intent_classes, pos_weight=1, input_dim=1024):
        super().__init__()
        self.pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id
        self.transformer = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
        self.domain_classifier = nn.Linear(input_dim, num_intent_classes)
        self.noise_classifier = nn.Linear(input_dim, 1)
        self.set_requires_grad()
        self.register_buffer("pos_weight", torch.Tensor([pos_weight]))

    def forward(self, x, mask=None):
        enc_last_hidden_state = self.transformer.model.encoder(x, attention_mask=mask)["last_hidden_state"]
        enc_summary = torch.mean(enc_last_hidden_state, dim=1)
        domain_logits = self.domain_classifier(enc_summary)
        noise_logits = self.noise_classifier(enc_summary)
        return domain_logits, noise_logits
    
    def set_requires_grad(self):
        # We freeze all the weights in transformer model, only training the final linear layer
        # so that we can combine this with the NLG model to save inference time
        for n, p in self.transformer.model.named_parameters():
            p.requires_grad = False

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        queries, domain_labels, noise_labels = batch
        attn_mask = (queries != self.pad_token_id).float()
        queries, domain_labels, noise_labels = queries, domain_labels, noise_labels
        domain_scores, noise_scores = self.forward(queries, attn_mask)
        
        domain_loss, noise_loss = self.loss_function(domain_scores, domain_labels, noise_scores, noise_labels)
        loss = domain_loss + noise_loss
        
        loss_dict = {
            "domain_loss": domain_loss,
            "noise_loss": noise_loss,
            "loss": loss
        }
        self.log_dict(loss_dict, prog_bar=True, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, logger=True)

        return loss
    
    def loss_function(self, domain_scores, domain_labels, noise_scores, noise_labels):
        domain_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(domain_scores, domain_labels[:,0])
        noise_loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=self.pos_weight)(noise_scores[:,0], noise_labels[:,0])
        return domain_loss, noise_loss
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
        return optimizer


def train_model_ligntning(model_name,
                          tokenizer,
                          num_intent_classes,
                          train_loader,
                          valid_loader,
                          checkpoint_dir,
                          num_epochs,
                          pos_weight,
                          n_gpus):
    
    model = MyModel(model_name, tokenizer, num_intent_classes, pos_weight=pos_weight)
    trainer = pl.Trainer(logger=True,
                         gpus=n_gpus,
                         accelerator="gpu",
                         max_epochs=num_epochs,
                         check_val_every_n_epoch=1,
                         default_root_dir=checkpoint_dir)
    trainer.fit(model=model,
                train_dataloaders=train_loader,
                val_dataloaders=valid_loader)
```

Comment: At a first glance it looks good, have you tried to disable the line `self.set_requires_grad()` in the `__init__` method?

Comment: @Bob I have the same line when training with vanilla pytorch in order to freeze the weight of the transformers part (the encoder specifically). I also see that I can do `self.transformer.eval()` to make the weights freeze during training. Are they different?

Comment: In the direction of making a minimal working example. Can you (a) reproduce the issue making `enc_last_hidden_state` the model input, and synthesizing some random data. or (b) extend your example some data that can be downloaded by anyone attempting to debug it?

Comment: It's internal data so I won't be able to share them, but I think (a) is a good idea. I will independently generate output of `enc_last_hidden_state` and just have a small linear prediction layer to test it out.

Comment: I understand. This happens with me as well. Sometimes I would like to ask a question but I don't because I am dealing with sensitive data. When I mentioned example data I was thinking about a subset of some public dataset.

Comment: @Bob Yeah, I get it. The only unsure thing is, I'm not sure if it's something with the model setup or it's something with the specific data that I'm using. I will test with (a) and get back to you once I have the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241179/discussion-between-tyz-and-bob).